# Eigenvalues of Orthogonal matrices and their ability to obtain exact values.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

It is well known that the eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices are of the form $\lambda=e^{i \phi}$ for some $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$.

If we want to take eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix, are we then able to obtain at least one eigenvalue of value exactly $\pm 1$ or shouldn't this exact value be possible due to notions from measure theory?

Comment: Argue the case of odd dimension, and that orthogonal matrices are real, so that eigenvalues come in complex-conjugate pairs or are real.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, what do you mean? I didn't quite follow

Comment: The characteristic polynomial has, as you already stated, only roots on the unit circle. It is also real. So if the degree is odd it has at least one real root on the unit circle. If the degree is even, then all roots can be complex-conjugate pairs not on the real axis.

Comment: @LutzLehmann , so if the degree is odd having an eigenvalue of $\pm 1$ shouldn't be possible?

Comment: No, quite the opposite, it is guaranteed.

Comment: @LutzLehmann , so for even degree the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix can get closer to -1, but not become exact -1 for example?

Comment: This claim fails the first sanity test of the identity matrix, or its negative. Or the example in the answer. With even degree you may or may not have real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Both eigenvalues are $1$.

Comment: Yes this is true, but it doesn't answer my question in general.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you, I'll make an edit.